# Displaying <div> in line when display in-line won't work

Tags: html, css

I have the HTML code below that creates a big div - used for spacing, a div that is used to create space from other divs and then the final div that holds the HTML code to be displayed but the divs are being displayed in a long list instead of rows:

```css
.product1, .product2, .product3, .product4, .product5, .product6, .product7, .product8, .product9, .product10, .product11, .product12, .product13, .product14, .product15 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.bufferContainer{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- iPhone 11 -->
    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product1">
        <p>iPhone 11 Pro Max</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product2">
        <p>iPhone 11 Pro</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product3">
        <p>iPhone 11</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- iPhone Xr -->
    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product4">
        <p>iPhone Xr</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- iPhone X -->
    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product5">
        <p>iPhone XS Max</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product6">
        <p>iPhone XS</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product7">
        <p>iPhone X</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- iPhone 8 -->
    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product8">
        <p>iPhone 8 Plus</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product9">
        <p>iPhone 8</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- iPhone 7 -->
    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product10">
        <p>iPhone 7 Plus</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product11">
        <p>iPhone 7</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- iPhone 6 -->
    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product12">
        <p>iPhone 6S Plus</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product13">
        <p>iPhone 6S</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product14">
        <p>iPhone 6 Plus</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bufferContainer">
    <div class="product15">
        <p>iPhone 6</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "container" class holds the "bufferContainer" and the "product1"

However, the web page is displayed as:

```
       [div]
       [div]
       [div]
```

etc...

Instead of :

```
      [div] [div] [div]
      [div] [div] [div]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `bufferContainer` class doesn't have the display inline.

Each of your products have the `bufferContainer` as a parent. Try giving the inline to your `bufferContainer` and you'll see them appear next to each other (might need to add a width to the `bufferContainer` as well

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this line, `.product1, .product2, .product3, .product4, .product5, .product6, .product7, .product8, .product9, .product10, .product11, .product12, .product13, .product14, .product15`, use `.bufferContainer`.

Your code will never work since they are children of `.bufferContainer`.

```css
.bufferContainer {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    height: 400px;
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.bufferContainer{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <!-- iPhone 11 -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product1">
                <p>iPhone 11 Pro Max</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product2">
                <p>iPhone 11 Pro</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product3">
                <p>iPhone 11</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- iPhone Xr -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product4">
                <p>iPhone Xr</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- iPhone X -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product5">
                <p>iPhone XS Max</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product6">
                <p>iPhone XS</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product7">
                <p>iPhone X</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- iPhone 8 -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product8">
                <p>iPhone 8 Plus</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product9">
                <p>iPhone 8</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- iPhone 7 -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product10">
                <p>iPhone 7 Plus</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product11">
                <p>iPhone 7</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- iPhone 6 -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product12">
                <p>iPhone 6S Plus</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product13">
                <p>iPhone 6S</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product14">
                <p>iPhone 6 Plus</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product15">
                <p>iPhone 6</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use flexbox:

Minimum changes to your code on a desktop would be:

```
 .bufferContainer{
  width:30%;
 }

.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
}
```

More info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Flex with solve this;

```css
.product1, .product2, .product3, .product4, .product5, .product6, .product7, .product8, .product9, .product10, .product11, .product12, .product13, .product14, .product15 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    height: 400px;
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.bufferContainer{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    flex: 0 0 30%;
    max-width: 30%;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <!-- iPhone 11 -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product1">
                <p>iPhone 11 Pro Max</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product2">
                <p>iPhone 11 Pro</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product3">
                <p>iPhone 11</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- iPhone Xr -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product4">
                <p>iPhone Xr</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- iPhone X -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product5">
                <p>iPhone XS Max</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product6">
                <p>iPhone XS</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product7">
                <p>iPhone X</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- iPhone 8 -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product8">
                <p>iPhone 8 Plus</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product9">
                <p>iPhone 8</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- iPhone 7 -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product10">
                <p>iPhone 7 Plus</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product11">
                <p>iPhone 7</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- iPhone 6 -->
            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product12">
                <p>iPhone 6S Plus</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product13">
                <p>iPhone 6S</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product14">
                <p>iPhone 6 Plus</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bufferContainer">
            <div class="product15">
                <p>iPhone 6</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How did I ?

```
.bufferContainer{
    ...
    flex: 0 0 30%;
    max-width: 30%;
}

.container {
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add float in this section -

```
.bufferContainer{
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```